# Nodejs - Axios post does not return anything in function

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I made a function on the node that makes a request to an api and I need to display *this answer on screen*, but it does **not return anything**, if I use *console.log* I can see the **DATE** in the answer, but if I give a **RETURN RES.DATA** it does *not display anything*, below is the function.

**getAllPrices:**

```
export default async function getAllPrices(vin) {
    try {
        await axios({  
            method: 'post',
            url: url,
            data: {
                "Cap": 51136.47,
                "DaysToFirstPayment":  30,
                "OnePay":false,
                "Rate":0.00006,
                "ResidualValue": vin,
                "Term":36,
                "Type": 0   
            }
        }).then(res => {
            return res; 
        });  
    } catch (err) {
        return err;
    }
}
```

**Vin parameter** = 28319.22

**Consuming function on the route:**

```
// GetAllPrices
routes.get('/getAllPrices/:vin', async (req, res) => {
    let { vin } = req.params;
    return res.json(await getAllPrices(vin));
});
```

Comment: You're using `await` together with `.then`, but you should use just one of them. The other thing that ins't working as expected is that you're returning `res` from a callback: `.then(res => { return res; });` and you're expecting that to be the return value of your `getAllPrices` function. You should probably update your `getAllPrices` function to something like this: `const res = await axios({//params}); return res.data;`

Comment: even if the request is a post method can I pass it in a variable?

update.
it works, thank u very much